# Tomcat temporary page during war deploying

Tags: jsp, tomcat, war

I need to configure Tomcat so that between starting the server and deploying wara showed a temporary page. There is a way without using redirects with Apache?

Comment: I always thought this should be in the servlet spec since almost everyone needs a way to indicate the app or server is unavailable for maintenance.